# PHPSpreadsheet generates empty file if it containts more than 16 rows

Tags: php, excel, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I am generating a xlsx file with PHPspreadshet and it always gives me an empty file (0kb) when it has more than 16 rows. I already tried to search for erros etc. and found nothing. It just depends on the row.
The Spreadsheet (Html for testing):
[image]

And when I switch following lines:

```
 $this->sheet->setCellValue("A16", "Besetzt");
```

To

```
 $this->sheet->setCellValue("A17", "Besetzt");
```

The generator (execute() is the entry point):

```
class ExcelOperation extends AbstractOperation
{

    private function addWork($cell, $name = "", $phone = ""){
        if($cell != null){
            $richText = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText();

            $boldText = $richText->createText($name);
            //$boldText->getFont()->setBold(true);
            $richText->createText("\n".$phone);
            $this->sheet->getCell($cell)->setValue($richText);
            $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
            $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        }

    }


    public function execute(WebRequest $wreq, WebResponse $wres){



        $eventId = $wreq->getParameter();

        $userId = "1839357067871549236";
        $calendar = $this->getCalendar($userId, $eventId);
        $eventStatistics = $this->getEventStatistics($eventId);


        //All Positions
        $this->renderPositionData($calendar);
        //$this->renderCurrentStatus($eventStatistics);

        $this->formatColumn("A");
        $this->formatColumn("B");
        $this->formatColumn("C");
        $this->formatColumn("D");

        //$writer = new Xlsx($this->spreadsheet);
        $writer = new Html($this->spreadsheet);
        $wres->success(true);
        $wres->set("filename", "Schichtplan.html");
        $wres->set("file", $writer->save('php://output'));
   }

   private function addFullBorder($from, $to){
      /*$styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'outline' => array(
                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
                'color' => array('argb' => PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_BLACK),
            ),
        ),
    );

    $this->sheet ->getStyle($from.':'.$to)->applyFromArray($styleArray);*/
   }

   private function renderCurrentStatus($statistics){

        $this->sheet->setCellValue("F2", "Stand");
        $this->sheet->mergeCells('F2:G2');
        $this->sheet->getStyle("F2")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $this->sheet->getStyle("F2")->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
        $this->sheet->getStyle("F2")->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB("A4DDF5");
        $this->sheet->getStyle("F2")->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_WHITE);


       $frei = $statistics["gesamt"]-($statistics["warten"]+$statistics["besetzt"]);
       $this->sheet->setCellValue("F2", "Frei");
       $this->sheet->setCellValue("G2", $frei);

       $this->sheet->setCellValue("F4", "Besetzt");
       $this->sheet->setCellValue("G4", $statistics["besetzt"]);

        $this->sheet->setCellValue("F6", "Wartend");
       $this->sheet->setCellValue("G6", $statistics["warten"]);

       $this->sheet->setCellValue("F8", "Gesamt");
       $this->sheet->setCellValue("G8", $statistics["gesamt"]);

       $this->addFullBorder("F2", "G8");
   }

   private function renderPositionData($calendar){
       foreach($calendar as $positionId => $position){
            $positionName = $position["position"]["alle_positionen_description"];
            preg_match('/Pos\. [0-9]+/', $positionName, $matches);
            $positionEndCell = null;
            $actualCol = $this->positionCount%$this->positionsPerLine;
            if(isset($matches[0])){
                $shortPositionName = $matches[0];
            }else{
                $shortPositionName = $positionName;
            }

            if($actualCol <5){
                $cell = $this->getCell($actualCol, $this->actualRowPerPosition);
                //var_dump($cell);
                //For Position header
                $this->actualRowPerPosition[$actualCol] += 1;
                $this->addPositionHeader($cell, $shortPositionName);
                $positionStartCell = $cell;
                //All shifts within this job
                foreach($position["jobs"] as $job){
                    //For Each Shift in Position
                    $cell = $this->getCell($actualCol, $this->actualRowPerPosition);
                    //$cell = "A17";
                    //var_dump($cell);
                    $this->sheet->setCellValue("A17", "Besetzt");

                    $formattedDateFrom = $this->dbDateToTime($job["job"]["alle_schichten_start"]);
                    $formattedDateTo = $this->dbDateToTime($job["job"]["alle_schichten_ende"]);

                    $this->addShiftHeader($cell, $formattedDateFrom." - ".$formattedDateTo);
                    $this->actualRowPerPosition[$actualCol] = 18;


                    $positionEndCell = $cell;
                   foreach($job["workers"] as $worker){
                        $fullName = $worker["firstname"]." ".$worker["secondname"];
                        $phone = "+43";

                        $cell = $this->getCell($actualCol, $this->actualRowPerPosition);
                        $this->addWork($cell, $fullName, $phone);
                        //$this->actualRowPerPosition[$actualCol] += 1;
                        $positionEndCell = $cell;
                    }
                }
                if($positionEndCell == null){
                    $positionEndCell = $positionStartCell;
                }
                $this->addFullBorder($positionStartCell, $positionEndCell);
                $this->positionCount++;
            }
        }

   }

   private function formatColumn($columnName){
       $this->sheet->getColumnDimension($columnName)->setWidth(35);
   }

   private function dbDateToTime(string $dateTime){
       $date = new \DateTime($dateTime);
        $formattedDateFrom = $date->format('H:i');
        return $formattedDateFrom;
   }

   private function getCell($actualCol, $actualRowPerPosition){
        $actualRow = $actualRowPerPosition[$actualCol]+1;
        $actualColName = $this->getColName($actualCol);
        $cell = $actualColName.$actualRow;
        $this->sheet->getRowDimension($actualRow)->setRowHeight(30);
        return $cell;
   }

   private function addPositionHeader($cell, $positionName){
       $this->sheet->setCellValue($cell, $positionName);

       //Font Color
        $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_WHITE);
        $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        //Background Color
        $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
        $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB("A4DDF5");
   }

   private function addShiftHeader($cell, $shiftText){
       $this->sheet->setCellValue($cell, $shiftText);
       $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
   }

   private function getColName($colId){
       $cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N"];
       return $cols[$colId];
   }

   private function getCalendar($userId, $eventId){
        $dbManager = new DbManager();
        $jobs = $dbManager->getAdminCalendarForUser($eventId, $userId);
        $calendar = $this->generateCalendarArray($jobs);
        return $calendar;
   }

   private function getEventStatistics($eventId){
       $dbManager = new DbManager();
       $eventStatistics = $dbManager->getEventStatistics($eventId);
       return $eventStatistics;
   }

    private function generateCalendarArray($jobs){
        $dbManager = new DbManager();
        $calendar = [];
        foreach ($jobs as $job) {
            if(!isset($calendar[$job["alle_positionen_id"]])){
                $jobFieldsWithValues = $this->getJobFieldsWithValues($dbManager, $job["alle_positionen_id"]);
                $job["needs_approval"] = $job["needs_approval"] ? true : false;
                $calendar[$job["alle_positionen_id"]] = 
                [
                    "position" =>$job,
                    "jobFieldsWithValues"=> $jobFieldsWithValues,
                    "jobs" => [],
                    "positionPermission"=>$job["positionPermission"]
                    ];
            }
            //Check if position has shift
            if($job["alle_schichten_id"] != null){
                 //Check if job in this shift (falsely defined as job) exists
                if(!isset($calendar[$job["alle_positionen_id"]]["jobs"][$job["alle_schichten_id"]])){
                    $calendar[$job["alle_positionen_id"]]["jobs"][$job["alle_schichten_id"]] = [
                                "job"=>$job,
                                "workers"=>[]
                                ];
                }
                if($job["Email"] != null){
                        $jobDef = [
                            "email"=>$job["Email"],
                            "approved"=>$job["Approved"],
                            "userId"=>$job["id"]."",
                            "firstname"=>$job["Vorname"],
                            "secondname"=>$job["Nachname"]
                            ];
                        array_push($calendar[$job["alle_positionen_id"]]["jobs"][$job["alle_schichten_id"]]["workers"], $jobDef);
                }
            }
        }
        return $calendar;
    }

    private function getJobFieldsWithValues(DbManager $dbManager, int $positionId) : array{
        $jobFieldsWithValues = [];
        $jobFields = $dbManager->getJobFieldsWithValues($positionId);
        foreach ($jobFields as $jobField) {
            if(isset($jobFieldsWithValues[$jobField["id"]])){
                array_push($jobFieldsWithValues[$jobField["id"]]["values"], ["data-value"=>$jobField["value"], "value"=>$jobField["value"]]);
            }else{
                $jobFieldsWithValues[$jobField["id"]] = [
                    "id"=>$jobField["id"],
                    "fieldBaseType"=>$jobField["fieldDataType"],
                    "name"=>$jobField["Bezeichnung"],
                    "description"=>$jobField["description"],
                    "values"=>[]];
                array_push($jobFieldsWithValues[$jobField["id"]]["values"], ["data-value"=>$jobField["value"], "value"=>$jobField["value"]]);

            }
        }
        return $jobFieldsWithValues;
    }

   public function __construct() {
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $this->positionsPerLine = 4;
        $this->actualRowPerPosition = [0,0,0,0];
        $this->positionCount = 0;

        $this->colors = [
            "black"=>\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_BLACK
            ];
   }

}
```

It generates an empty file.

Comment: Where is your code? Show us the code and describe the error you are getting if you are using error reporting. How do you fill the cells?

Comment: I don't get more errors than these show in the image and these Warnings. I fill the Cels with setCellValue(string, string) in a loop and when It exeeds the row 16 I get an empty file.

Comment: OK, can you show your code? You can use `fromArray($array, NULL, 'A1');` In that way you don't need loop and complete array will be written in excel file. It's a native function on PHPSpreadsheet.

Comment: Okay, i just added the code. Thanks!